# How to add legend(displaying text against colors) in a colored google bar chart?

Tags: java, google-maps, charts, google-visualization

I am drawing a chart on a google map. The chart has 3-5 bars of different colors. As the space under the x axis is not very much, I would like to add a legend on right-top of the bar. The legend should visually show which color is what text(i cant add an image because i dont have the reputation=10).

What parameters I should use in my code :

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'ONE', { role: 'style' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 'color: white'],
    ['2020', 14, 'color: gray'],
    ['2030', 16, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2040', 22, 'color: green'],
    ['2050', 28, 'color: red']
  ]);


    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Revenue per Year',      //main title
                   'width':500,                     //pixel density 
                   'height':500,                    //pixel density
                    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},       //width of the vertical bars
                    legend: { position: "right", maxLines: 3 }, //none=dont show legends
                    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },    //!!NOTE: this is needed for transparency and to remove white background
                    titleTextStyle: { color: 'red',fontSize: 24},
                    //options for vertical axis(Y)
                    vAxis: {
                    textStyle:{color: '#FFF',fontSize: 24},
                            slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:60                   // here you can even use 180
                            },
                    //options for horizontal access(X)
                    hAxis: {
                    textStyle:{color: '#FFF',fontSize: 24},
                            direction:-1, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:60             // here you can even use 180
                            }
                   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you want to use an [annotation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole)

annotations are provided using a column role,
similar to the `role: 'style'` column already being used...

you can add the annotation values to the data,
or use a view to provide a calculated column,
as in the following working snippet...

---

**note:**

annotations by default will appear on the ends of the bars,
in the case of this chart, the far left of the bar

there are no standard [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) for annotation placement,
but you can manually move the annotations,
by changing the `x` attribute on the `<text>` element

just keep in mind, custom modifications will not be reflected when using `getImageURI`,
if you need to produce a png image of the chart

also, the chart will move the annotations back to their original location,
anytime there interactivity, such as column hover

*so must use a* `MutationObserver` to move them back, when activity occurs...

---

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'ONE', { role: 'style' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 'color: white'],
    ['2020', 14, 'color: gray'],
    ['2030', 16, 'color: yellow'],
    ['2040', 22, 'color: green'],
    ['2050', 28, 'color: red']
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Revenue per Year',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '95%'
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      fill: 'transparent'
    },
    titleTextStyle: {
      color: 'red',
      fontSize: 24
    },
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        color: '#FFF',
        fontSize: 24
      },
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 60
    },
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        color: '#FFF',
        fontSize: 24
      },
      direction: -1,
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 60
    }
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    role: 'annotation',
    sourceColumn: 0,
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

  // move annotations
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(annotation) {
      // identify annotation -- could be tooltip label
      if ((annotation.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'start') &&
          (annotation.getAttribute('fill') !== '#000000')) {
        var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
        var annotationBounds = annotation.getBBox();
        var annotationPadding = 4;
        annotation.setAttribute('x',
          chartLayout.getXLocation(0) - annotationBounds.width - annotationPadding
        );
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. the code worked :-). I customized it to suit the app i am working on.